# Remove subsequent duplicate string in a column of table

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I have a table named `event`

```
id     event_sequnce
1      a->c->b->b->b->c->b
2      d->d->a->d->c->a->a->c
```

I want to remove the subsequent duplicate letter from the column `event_sequnce`

so output table will be

```
id   event_sequnce
1    a->c->b->c->b
2    d->a->d->c->a->c
```

How to write query to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use regex for it:

```
select regexp_replace('d->d->a->d->c->a->a->c', '(\w\-\>)\1+', '\1', 'g');
```

[image]

Update version

```
select regexp_replace(regexp_replace(textcat('d->d->a->d->c->a->a->c->c', '->'), '(\w\-\>)\1+', '\1', 'g'), '\-\>$', '');
```

Comment: doesn't work if duplicate at the end ex: 'd->d->a->d->c->a->a->c->c'

Comment: @RémyBaron you may append `->` at the end of string, run `regexp_replace` and remove `->` it from the end. Or you can rewrite the regex a little :)

Comment: or : select regexp_replace(regexp_replace('d->d->a->d->c->a->a->c->c->c', '(\w\-\>)\1+', '\1', 'g'),'(\w)\-\>\1','\1');